# vmware esxi 6 aborded on the boot sequence

Tags: esxi

I had an Esxi 6 Server. After power off and on, the Esxi system aborded on

"chardevs loaded successiful" or "chardevs loaded sucdevs".

I will make a try using the usb stick to repair it. If you have some experience, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I used esxi usb stick to boot the machine, and i want to boot to the recovery mode, but after it boots, it let to choose which harddisk to install, I do not go on, and Rebooted.

Remove the USB stick, and boot with the harddisk , and it works, so , reboot is everything ,aha.